# Timeout exception after upgrading to infispan 8.2

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan

Infinispan times out when I try to start a cache after upgrading to infinispan 8.2.2.

I use the following configuration:

```
Configuration createConfiguration(boolean persistent) {

LockingConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC).sync()
        .replTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .persistence()
            .passivation(Boolean.FALSE)
            .addClusterLoader().preload(false).shared(Boolean.FALSE)
            .remoteCallTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .transaction()
        .transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
        .transactionManagerLookup(new JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup())
        .syncRollbackPhase(Boolean.TRUE)
        .syncCommitPhase(Boolean.TRUE)
        .lockingMode(LockingMode.PESSIMISTIC)
        .cacheStopTimeout(30000l)
        .useSynchronization(true)
        .recovery().disable().locking();
confBuilder.clustering().stateTransfer().timeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
if(persistent) {
    confBuilder.persistence().addSingleFileStore()
                .location("/somepath").fetchPersistentState(Boolean.TRUE)
                .preload(false).purgeOnStartup(false)
                .expiration().lifespan(-1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}
confBuilder.validate();
return confBuilder.build();
}
```

After seeing the following information:

```
 2016-06-10 12:17:53,349 INFO  [CacheStartThread,null,XXX] lookup.JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup (JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup.java:56) - ISPN000107: Retrieving transaction manager Transaction: unknown
```

The application times out for a while before this error is thrown (the timeout is configurable in our code):

```
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000402: Timeout waiting for view 0. Current view is 0, current status is RECOVERING_CLUSTER
at org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl.waitForJoinerView(ClusterTopologyManagerImpl.java:535) ~[infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl.handleJoin(ClusterTopologyManagerImpl.java:207) ~[infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.topology.CacheTopologyControlCommand.doPerform(CacheTopologyControlCommand.java:171) ~[infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.topology.CacheTopologyControlCommand.perform(CacheTopologyControlCommand.java:153) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl.executeOnCoordinator(LocalTopologyManagerImpl.java:606) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.topology.LocalTopologyManagerImpl.join(LocalTopologyManagerImpl.java:139) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start(StateTransferManagerImpl.java:110) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168) [infinispan-commons-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:859) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:628) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:617) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:542) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:238) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:849) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:635) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:585) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.access$100(DefaultCacheManager.java:125) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager$1.run(DefaultCacheManager.java:485) [infinispan-core-8.2.2.Final.jar:8.2.2.Final]
2016-06-10 12:18:54,516 WARN  [CacheStartThread,null,KeyCache] topology.CacheTopologyControlCommand (CacheTopologyControlCommand.java:159) - ISPN000071: Caught exception when handling command CacheTopologyControlCommand{cache=KeyCache, type=JOIN, sender=oliver-Predator-4829, joinInfo=CacheJoinInfo{consistentHashFactory=org.infinispan.distribution.ch.impl.SyncReplicatedConsistentHashFactory@65541715, hashFunction=MurmurHash3, numSegments=256, numOwners=2, timeout=60000, totalOrder=false, distributed=false}, topologyId=0, rebalanceId=0, currentCH=null, pendingCH=null, availabilityMode=null, actualMembers=null, throwable=null, viewId=0}
```

---

My pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.jbossts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
            <version>4.16.6.Final</version>
```

This is related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37728067/preloading-issue-with-infinispan-not-instance-of-advancedcacheloader/37740146).

Comment: Hmmm, could be due to a library compatibility issue, see [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JDG-425) (root cause is [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JDG-114)). So maybe try to enable TRACE logging on org.infinispan package and see if you can find out more.

Comment: Yes, it might be. We also use hibernate 4.1.10.Final. There might be a class for jboss logging... Tried adding jboss-logging as a separate artifact to my pom. Which version is required?

Comment: The JBoss Logging version used by Infinispan 8.2.2 is defined [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/8.2.2.Final/bom/pom.xml#L74). You should check what Hibernate and other dependencies you might have require.

Comment: Any one find the fix? I got the same error after upgrading to 9.1.1 version

Comment: I don't remember. I think not, but check the annotations you use for callback methods. Some were changed between versions and no error was thrown if you didn't use the annotations (sorry for very inprecis answer and if I say something wrong here. I don't work on this anymore and have forgotten a few details... The thing with annotations wasn't infinispan's fault; it was application specific)

Comment: Can you help me with some pointers please?